# Contour Integration of Complex Numbers -- question 1

Tags: complex-analysis, self-learning, contour-integration

I make up my own questions and contours and solve the integration problem without knowing whether the answer is right or not. Please verify the below question for me:

$f(z) = z^2 + e^z$ *and* $\gamma(t)=t+(2t)i$. Calculate $\int_cf(z)dz$

*Step1:* Replace $z$ in $f(z)$ with $x+iy$. Expand the bracket. Bring like terms together.
*Result:* $f(z) = (x^2-y^2)+[2i(xy)+e^z]$

*Step2:* Calculate $\gamma\prime(t)$
*Result:* $1+2i$

*Step3:* Calculate $f(\gamma(t))$
*Result:* $-3t^2 + (4t^2)i + e^{t+2ti}$

*Step4:* Calculate $f(\gamma(t))\times\gamma\prime(t)$
*Result:* $-11t^2 - 2t^2i + e^{t+2ti}[1+2i]$

*Step5:* Calculate the integral
*Result:* $-\frac{11t^3}{3}-\frac{2it^3}{3}+e^{1+2ti}[1+2i]$

*Step6:* Evaluating from 0 to 1
*Result* $-\frac{11}{3}-\frac{2i}{3}+0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have calculated the integral incorrectly. When you integrate $\int_0^1 e^{t+2ti}dt=\int_0^1 e^{(1+2i)t}dt=[\frac{1}{1+2i}e^{(1+2i)t}]_0^1=\frac{1}{1+2i}[e^{(1+2i)t}]_0^1$, and that saves you some work, because it will cancel out the other factor $1+2i$. I get that this leaves $e^{1+2i}-1$ plus what you get from the $z^2$.

Comment: Ok so 2 out of 3 terms are correct. :) This is the same as $e^{nx}$ :) got my mistake